# doctrine 2 returns errror 'proxy directory must be writable'

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

i am using doctrine 2 with Zendframework 2

i am trying to return an object but keep getting this error:

> Your proxy directory must be writable

this is my query:

```
$this->getEntityManager()
                    ->getRepository('Messages\Entity\Messages')
                    ->findOneBy(array('id' => 6,
                                      'receiverId' => 16
                   ));
```

However, the same query return an array without any problems re:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

     $qb->select(array('u'))
        ->from('Messages\Entity\Messages','u')
        ->where('u.id = :id')  
        ->andWhere('u.receiverUserId = :receiverId')    
        ->setParameter('receiverId',16)    
        ->setParameter('id',(int)6);

      $query = $qb->getQuery();
        return   $data = $query->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: Check for the permissions of the directory. It should be writable not only by you (user) but also by the group. Right click on the folder and go to properties, then permissions, or do it from the terminal using `chmod` (it actually depends on your particular setup of php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zend Framework 2 How To Set Doctrine 2 Proxy Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599208/zend-framework-2-how-to-set-doctrine-2-proxy-directory)

Comment: I had a similar error. If you are running a script/process via the command line, like I was trying to do, make sure you are using the proper user. It's sometimes easier to sudo to the apache user to make sure you'll have permissions to the various files and folders.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration` you can simply fix it by

1. Create the following directory in your project root. `data/DoctrineORMModule/Proxy`
2. `chmod -R 755 data/DoctrineORMModule/Proxy`

In your bootstrap include the path to the data directory as in:

`Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__ . "/src/models"), $this->isDevMode, "data/DoctrineORMModule/Proxy")`

That fixed it for me.

Comment: This helped me too! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Proxies** are simple classes which extends your actual entities and used internally by doctrine to hydrate associations of your entities by [lazy-loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) them. Doctrine decides to use or not to use a proxy instances on runtime for different situations and it really depends on your queries and associations in your entities. You may want to read about this subject in-depth at [official documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html).

In your case, doctrine trying to generate a proxy class for your `Messages` entity but your proxy directory is simply not writable as error output's said.

This seems like *misconfiguration* of DoctineModule. (Assuming that you are using [DoctrineORMModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule) to integrate doctrine with ZF2) Doctrine needs a writeable directory to put that generated proxy classes. For ZF2's view, `data` directory on application root perfectly fits for this requirement.

1. Make sure existence of the line below in your `public/index.php`:

   ```
   chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
   ```
2. and try to use a configuration like this:

   ```
   <?php
   /**
    * module/Application/config/module.config.php
    */
   return array(
       'router' => array(
            // ...
       ),

       // ...

       'doctrine' => array(
           'driver' => array(
              //...
           ),

           /**
            * Generating proxies on runtime and using array cache instead of apc(u)
            * greatly reduces the performance. So, you may want to override 
            * this settings on production environment.
            */
           'configuration' => array(
               'orm_default' => array(
                   'metadata_cache' => 'array',
                   'query_cache' => 'array',
                   'result_cache' => 'array',
                   'hydration_cache' => 'array',
                   'generate_proxies' => true,
                   'proxy_dir' => 'data/DoctrineORMModule/Proxy',
                   'proxy_namespace' => 'DoctrineORMModule\Proxy',
               ),
           ),
        )
    );
   ```

Comment: Hello Foozy, i tried your suggestion but it did not work. its still  giving the same error message

Comment: Do you have any suggestions. I appreciate your assistance foozy. thank you

Comment: The problem is clear: your proxy directory (data in my example) must  be writeable by your http server's user. What is your OS and http server?

Comment: hi Foozy. sorry. what is an OS?. for amy Http server i am using wamp:

Comment: for my http server, i am using                       http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: I see, you are running wamp on windows which is your OS. Did you try the same configuration by replacing slashes with the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Fedora 24, enter the following commands:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/html/YOUR_SITE/data';
restorecon -v '/var/www/html/YOUR_SITE/data'
```

With this, you are changing the label of the `/var/www/html` and giving write permission to `httpd`.