# ZF2 + Doctrine - Proxy Directory must be writable [fedora 23 + apache]

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, fedora-23

I have made an application in Zend Framework 2 + Doctrine, and it worked normally in Ubuntu, I am now using Fedora 23 and I am getting the following error:

**Your proxy directory "data/DoctrineORMModule/Proxy" must be writable**

I have used **chmod 755** and **777** but still the error persists.

```
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'configuration' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'metadata_cache' => 'array',
                'query_cache' => 'array',
                'result_cache' => 'array',
                'hydration_cache' => 'array',
                'generate_proxies' => true,
                'proxy_dir' => 'data/DoctrineORMModule/Proxy',
                'proxy_namespace' => 'DoctrineORMModule\Proxy',
            )
        ),
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'port' => '3306',
                    'user' => 'root',
                    'password' => '',
                    'dbname' => 'mydatabase',
                    'driverOptions' => array(
                        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
                    )
                )
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

My operating system is **Fedora 23** and I'm using **Apache**.

Below is the code of my virtual host:

(i used the same example from zend framework website)

```
<VirtualHost myapplication.com:80>
    ServerName   myapplication
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vhosts-projects/myapplication/public

    RewriteEngine off

    <Location />
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

What might be happening? 
**Already looked at other similar topics but none solved.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zend Framework 2 How To Set Doctrine 2 Proxy Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599208/zend-framework-2-how-to-set-doctrine-2-proxy-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure user have access to all directories in the path, not only `Proxy`.