# Doctrine settings for proxy

Tags: php, centos, doctrine, plesk

I'm programming a web application with Doctrine 2 on a CentOS 7 server, with Plesk and PHP 7.3.

I'm getting the error message that I have to configure a proxy directory when I run the web application. On my test system (local) it works without any issues.

What can I do to fix this problem?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Doctrine\Common\Proxy\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: You must configure a proxy directory. See docs for details in /var/www/vhosts/.../vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/Exception/InvalidArgumentException.php:23 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/.../vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php(199): Doctrine\Common\Proxy\Exception\InvalidArgumentException::proxyDirectoryRequired() #1 /var/www/vhosts/.../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php(77): Doctrine\Common\Proxy\ProxyGenerator->__construct(false, 'Proxies') #2 /var/www/vhosts/.../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php(167): Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory->__construct(Object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager), false, 'Proxies', 1) #3 /var/www/vhosts/.../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php(8 in /var/www/vhosts/.../vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/Exception/InvalidArgumentException.php on line 23

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zend Framework 2 How To Set Doctrine 2 Proxy Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599208/zend-framework-2-how-to-set-doctrine-2-proxy-directory)

Comment: I'm afraid not. I can't find the corresponding directory. But I don't use another framework either. I have changed the permissions. But it doesn't work either.